# Change the value of variables that occur 80% of the times in each row, R

Tags: r, categorical-data

In my data, I have 74 observations (rows) and 128 variables (columns), where each variable takes either 0 or 1 as value. In R, I am trying to write a code, where I can find in each row, the variables that has 1 as value and calculate 80% of the times 1 appears in each row. Pick those variables that has 80% of the times value as 1 and change the value from 1 to 0. I could write code, where I can calculate the 80% of times, 1 appears in each row, but I am not able to pick these variables in each row and change their value from 1 to 0.

```
data# data frame with 74 observations and 128 variables

row1 <- data[1,]
count1 <- length(which(data[1,] == 1)) # #number of 1 in row 1
print(count1)
perform <- 80/100*count1# 80% of count1
```

Below code works for one row:

```
test <- t(apply(data[1,], 1, function(x,n){

  onesInX <- which(x==1)

  # Randomly select 80% of 1 and change to 0

  x[sample(onesInX, floor(length(onesInX)*.8))] <- 0

  x
}))
```

If specify all the rows, code is not working:

```
test <- t(apply(data[1:74,], 1, function(x,n){
 onesInX <- which(x==1)
  # Randomly select 80% of 1 and change to 0
  x[sample(onesInX, floor(length(onesInX)*.8))] <- 0
  x
 }))
```

*Example of desired output:*

## original data frame

```
 df

   a b c d e f
1  1 1 1 1 1 1
2  1 0 1 1 0 1
3  1 1 1 0 1 1
```

When the code is applied to all the three rows in df, output should like this in all the three rows (80% of 1 replaced as 0):

```
   a  b  c  d  e  f
1  1  0  0  0  1  0
2  0  0  1  0  0  0
3  0  1  1  0  0  0
```

Thanks

Any suggestions

Thank you

Priya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use `apply` row-wise and get indices where value is `1` using `which`. Afterwards, pick `80%` of those indices (with value as 1) using `sample` and replace those to '0`.

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x){
           onesInX <- which(x==1)
           # Randomly select 80% of 1 and change to 0
           x[sample(onesInX, floor(length(onesInX)*.8))] <- 0
           x
          }))

#      a b c d e f
# [1,] 0 0 0 1 0 0
# [2,] 0 0 0 1 0 0
# [3,] 0 0 1 0 0 1
# [4,] 0 1 0 0 0 0
# [5,] 0 1 0 0 0 0
# [6,] 1 0 0 0 0 0
# [7,] 0 0 0 0 0 1
# [8,] 0 0 1 0 0 0
# [9,] 0 0 1 0 1 0
# [10,] 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

**Sample Data:**

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(c(0,1,1,1), 10, replace = TRUE),
                 b = sample(c(0,1,1,1), 10, replace = TRUE),
                 c = sample(c(0,1,1,1), 10, replace = TRUE),
                 d = sample(c(0,1,1,1), 10, replace = TRUE),
                 e = sample(c(0,1,1,1), 10, replace = TRUE),
                 f = sample(c(0,1,1,1), 10, replace = TRUE))

df

#    a b c d e f
# 1  1 0 1 1 1 1
# 2  1 0 0 1 1 1
# 3  1 1 1 1 1 1
# 4  1 1 0 0 1 0
# 5  0 1 1 1 1 0
# 6  1 1 1 1 1 0
# 7  1 1 0 1 0 1
# 8  1 1 1 0 1 1
# 9  1 1 1 1 1 1
# 10 0 1 1 1 1 1

# Answer on OP's data
t(apply(df1, 1, function(x){
           onesInX <- which(x==1)
           x[sample(onesInX, floor(length(onesInX)*.8))] <- 0
           x
          }))

#   a b c d e f
# 1 1 1 0 0 0 0     <- .8*6 = 4.8 => 4 has been converted to 0
# 2 0 0 0 1 0 0     <- .8*5 = 4.0 => 4 has been converted to 0
# 3 0 1 0 0 0 0     <- .8*4 = 3.2 => 3 has been converted to 0 


# Data from OP

df1 <- read.table(text="
a b c d e f
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 1 0 1 1 0 1
3 1 1 1 0 1 1",
header = TRUE)  

df1
#   a b c d e f
# 1 1 1 1 1 1 1    <- No of 1 = 6
# 2 1 0 1 1 0 1    <- No of 1 = 4
# 3 1 1 1 0 1 1    <- No of 1 = 5
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. But I want 80% of the times, number 1 occurs in each row. For example, in row 1, out of 128 variables, 4 variables show value as 1, calculate 80% of the times number 1 occurs in row 1. In row 1, 80% of 4 is 3.2, so the code should select 3 variables out of 4 and change their value to 0.

Comment: @Priya Ahh. Thats fine. You can even do that very easily. Do you want selection to be random to set 80% variables to 0? It would be best if you can modify (few rows) the sample data used by me and update it for expected output.

Comment: @Priya I have updated my answer. Have a look. Probably that is what you were looking for. If answer helps you then you can accept answer by clicking on `tick` symbol in left of answer box.

Comment: Thank you once again for the code. I am able to do it for one row, when I specify all the rows, the code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Priya What do you mean when you say you specify all rows? What did you try? Please share your code.

Comment: I have given the code in the above question. Thanks

Comment: @Priya My code work for multiple rows as well. It will take 1 row at a time and calculate `80%` of occurrence and then replace. I'm just wondering why have you added another argument as `n` in `function` used for `apply`. If your purpose is to calculate `80%` 1 on all rows then solution can be different.

Comment: @Priya Why dont you first try with my code with my data and check output? In case your expectation is different then please provide expected output so that people can help you.

Comment: I have provided an example in the question. Thanks

Comment: @Priya I have updated my answer to include data provided by you. I have annotated the answer to add logical explanation. Have a look.

Comment: Now the code is working. I had one column in my data, which was coded as "positive" and "negative". When I changed the values of positive as 1 and negative as 0, the code started working. Many thanks